# Binding issue with LongListSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

First time caller, long time listener...
I have been pounding my head against a data binding issue all day and am at a loss.  I am attempting to display a list of links with a LongListSelector for Windows Phone 8.

I have an class representing the Link (ExternalLink)

I have a class representing the collection of links (ExternalLinkList)

I have verified that the Collection gets loaded with the correct data without an issue. Given the code below can someone point me to what I am sure is a mindbogglingly obvious issue that I am just now seeing?

```
public class ExternalLink
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Property for link title
    /// </summary>        
    public String Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for link text
    /// </summary>        
    public String Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for link image name. 
    /// </summary>        
    public String ImageName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for item text
    /// </summary>        
    public String Link { get; set; }

    public ExternalLink(string title, string text, string imagename, string link)
    {
        Title = title;
        Text = text;
        ImageName = imagename;
        Link = link;
    }

    public ExternalLink()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }

    public Uri Url
    {
        get
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(Link, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            return uri;
        }
        set
        {
            Url = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The collection code (updated):

```
public class ExternalLinkList
{
    private ObservableCollection<ExternalLink> list;

    public ObservableCollection<ExternalLink> List
    {
        get
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new ObservableCollection<ExternalLink>();
            }
            return list;
        }
        set
        {
            if (list != value)
            {
                list = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ExternalLinkList()
    {

    }
}
```

The view model code:

```
public partial class LinkListPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static ExternalLinkList List {get; set;}

    public static Uri LinkListXML = new Uri("/GenericRssReader;component/pagelinklist.xml", UriKind.Relative);

    public static string imagePathTo = "/GenericRssReader;Assets/LinkImages/";

    public LinkListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += LinkListPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void LinkListPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List = new ExternalLinkList();

        StreamResourceInfo xml = App.GetResourceStream(LinkListXML);
        ParseOPML(xml.Stream, imagePathTo);
        //MessageBox.Show("test " + List.List.Count);

        LinkList.ItemsSource = List.List;
    }

    private static void ParseOPML(Stream stream, string pathto)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);

        // XML parsed using Linq
        ExternalLink lin = null;

        foreach(XElement outline in xDocument.Descendants("outline"))
        {
            string ImageName = pathto + outline.Attribute("imageName").Value;
            lin = new ExternalLink(outline.Attribute("title").Value, 
                outline.Attribute("text").Value, 
                ImageName, 
                outline.Attribute("xmlUrl").Value);

            List.List.Add(lin);
            //MessageBox.Show(lin.Title + "\n" + lin.Text + "\n" + lin.ImageName + "\n" + lin.Link);
        }

        //MessageBox.Show("Title 0: " + List.List[0].Title + "\n ImageName 0: " + List.List[0].ImageName);
    }
}
```

xaml code

```
<phone:LongListSelector 
    x:Name="LinkList" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
    Margin="5,0,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    DataContext="local:ExternalLink"
    SelectionChanged="LinkList_SelectionChanged"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorizontalTileDataTemplate}"
    >
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: do you get any errors or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Nope the binding just fails silently and no data gets displayed.

Comment: Good point, I added the accessors however and the binding is still failing.  Code above updated.

Comment: Is that `DataContext` correct? I haven't tried building any WP8 apps, but usually the `DataContext` is bound to an instance of a `ViewModel`, or say, to the control code behind with `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" (E.g. At the Window/Control level)`.

Comment: Tried changing the Binding to self without any luck.

Comment: What is `local:ExternalLink`?

Comment: It is what came out of the VS binding tool when I tried to set the context to ExternalLink...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved my problem by changing the LongListSelector to a ListBox. Once I did this the problem went away.  I don't know if this is just another bug in LLS or if there was something that I was missing but functionality wise I don't seem to be missing anything I need so this is the way I am moving forward...
Thanks for everyone's comments.